# UIWebView with jwplayer

Tags: ios, swift, safari, uiwebview

I have a link for streaming live TV: "http://tv.tivi24h.com/2014/04/htv-thao-1.html. If I open this link by browsers like Firefox and Chrome, it works well and shows the live video.

However, it doesn't work with Safari. In addition, because I want to show the live video in an iOS app, I use UIWebView.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tvLink = "http://tv.tivi24h.com/2014/04/htv-thao-1.html"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
                let wv:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
                self.view.addSubview(wv)
                wv.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: tvLink)!))
    }
 }
```

And as you can guess, it doesn't work, too. I noticed that the live TV uses jwplayer, but I couldn't figure out how to play it on UIWebView or Safari. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your jwplayer to a version that can play in HTML5. You currently have 6.

SINGLE PLAYER FOR HTML5 & FLASH
JW Player 7 will intelligently switch between Flash and HTML5 within a single playlist -- yet another way to provide a great experience for viewers everywhere. And more flexibility for monetization, too.
http://jw7.jwplayer.com